# Char to Date in Oracle

Tags: oracle, date, char

I am trying to run a very basic query off of a date which is defined as a char(18) the results for the field show as 07082015 (for 07/08/15).

```
  select *
  from ELECT_REMIT_RESP_HDR_FCT b
  where b.OFFICE_NBR = '1234' and b.INV_NBR = '123456'
  b.CRTD_DT = '07082015'
```

I have tried the to_date function and was received an error saying month was not valid.

Comment: Aside from the standard question of why you would store a date in a column with the wrong data type and why you'd use a `char(18)` when you want to store an 8 character string, I'm not sure what the question is.  Does the query you posted not work?  If so, in what way?  Why would you use the `to_date` function?

Comment: @JustinCave unfortunately I did not create the db and do not have the pull to make changes to how data is stored. The query I have above does not return results however I can see that date in the results if I remove the date part of the where clause. So I thought maybe I should convert to a date just as an option to try to see if I would get results, no such luck.

Comment: Can you put together a test case that demonstrates the problem?  Ideally something on sqlfiddle?  My guess is that there is more stored in the column than just the day (since otherwise a `char(18)` is beyond silly).

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue though it doesn't seem right, it ran and worked! I just removed the single quotes from the 07082015.

Comment: By removing the quotes, you are treating `07082015` as a number rather than a string.  This means that Oracle is converting the string values stored in the column to numbers then doing the comparison.  As you say, it works but is not really right.  My guess, since the field is CHAR(18), is that it is padded with spaces.  I wonder if you would get results by using `b.CRTD_DT=LPAD('07082015',18)`, or the same using RPAD instead of LPAD, or `TRIM(b.CRTD_DT)='07082015'`.